# Difference between 自己 and 自分

Tags: word-choice, nuances, nouns

I am wondering if there are any differences in the usage of `自己` and `自分`, or are they simply synonyms?

It seems that the two are interchangeable with nouns stemming from them.

I.e, `非自己` and `非自分` also appear to be synonyms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the meaning is about 'self'. Now there are differences in the two words. I myself am not really sure about all the little differences in meaning of these two words. But I am pretty sure that in certain cases, it's not interchangeable. So to answer your question, I would like to give you some phrases about each one.

> 自分はそう思う。 *Methinks*
>
> 自分なりにやる。 *Do something in one's own way*
>
> 自分自身 *Me, myself*
>
> 両親のためではなく、自分のために勉強する *To study for myself not for my parents*
>
> 自分で決める *Decide it by myself*

---

> 自己紹介 *Introducing oneself* I'm pretty sure they don't use 自分紹介
>
> 自己主義 自己中心 *Egoism, selfish*
>
> 自己宣伝 *To advertise oneself*
>
> 自己流 *Self-taught, one's own way*
>
> 自己批判 *Criticizing oneself*

So in conclusion the two are a bit like myself vs oneself/self. And some sites said that it's the subjective self (自分 = I, me) vs objective self (自己, oneself).

Also there are other words that you might be interested in too.

> [自我]{じが} (means *ego*)、 [自]{みずか}ら means *himself/oneself*.

In fact, [自]{みずか}ら is a bit like himself. Sample sentences from Weblio:

> 彼は自らを[省]{かえり}みる *He reviews himself*
>
> 社長自ら[指揮]{しき}をとる *The CEO himself takes command of sth.*

Comment: Going through your summary, it seems that 自分 is a recursive pronoun while 自己 is a noun. For example, 自分主義 would sound as amateurish as Me-ism. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer.    It highlights the differences quite nicely.

Answer (score -3):

Synonyms.
自己 is a little bit formal/academic.

Comment: Are you saying they are always interchangeable?

Comment: Yes, except used as an idiom.

Comment: ^ でも・・・「自分のことは自分でやりなさい！」とは言えますが「自己のことは自己でやりなさい！」とは言わないですよね・・　軍隊でも「自分に（＝私に）やらせてください」を「自己にやらせてください」とは言わないですよね・・

Comment: You are right. When you use 自分 to mean 私(I), you cannot use 自己 instead. 自分=自己(when 自分 means “self”.